# What's the benefit to slowing time with the Bullet Time card in Golfie?

Tags: golfie

In **Golfie**, there's a card called *Bullet Time* which slows down time by 25%. That's great and all, but I don't understand why I actually *care* about slowing down time. Once you fire a ball, you no longer have any control of it, so the slow effect doesn't help at all from what I can tell.

The only usage I can think of is that there are some other cards with activation abilities (like Jetpack), but they're all rare cards too, meaning Bullet Time would be completely useless unless you've got another very specific rare card in your deck.  I can only assume there's something I'm missing here, and that's some other usage or interaction for Bullet Time.

[image: bullet time: slow speed by 25%]

**What's the benefit to slowing time with Bullet Time?**

Comment: Are there any kind of timers or time limits in this game? Maybe you don't slow down time, but instead slow down these "timers" by 25%

Comment: @TimmyJim Nope. The only limiting factors is a health bar and number of strokes you can make.